# Unable to serve static resources from classpath using vertx-web

Tags: java, vert.x, java-vertx-web

[The vertx-web documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/js/#_serving_static_resources) says that it is possible to serve static resources from the classpath, and everything I've read in forum/help threads seems to confirm this. Unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work.

```java
public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  @Override
  public void start() {
    final Router router = Router.router(vertx);

    router.get("/greeting").handler(req -> req.response().end("Hello Vert.x!"));

    router.route("/*").handler(StaticHandler.create());

    vertx.createHttpServer()
        .requestHandler(router)
        .listen(8080);
  }

}
```

```java
@ExtendWith(VertxExtension.class)
class MainVerticleTest {

  @BeforeEach
  void prepare(Vertx vertx, VertxTestContext testContext) {
    vertx.deployVerticle(MainVerticle.class.getCanonicalName(), testContext.succeeding(id -> testContext.completeNow()));
  }

  @Test
  @DisplayName("Check that the server returns greeting")
  void checkServerHasStarted(Vertx vertx, VertxTestContext testContext) {
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(vertx);
    webClient.get(8080, "localhost", "/greeting")
      .as(BodyCodec.string())
      .send(testContext.succeeding(response -> testContext.verify(() -> {
        assertEquals(200, response.statusCode());
        assertTrue(response.body().length() > 0);
        assertTrue(response.body().contains("Hello Vert.x!"));
        testContext.completeNow();
      })));
  }

  @Test
  @DisplayName("Check that the server returns router-root.txt")
  void checkServerHasRootResource(Vertx vertx, VertxTestContext testContext) {
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(vertx);
    webClient.get(8080, "localhost", "/router-root.txt")
      .as(BodyCodec.string())
      .send(testContext.succeeding(response -> testContext.verify(() -> {
        assertEquals(200, response.statusCode());
        testContext.completeNow();
      })));
  }

    
  @Test
  @DisplayName("Check that the server returns router-package.txt")
  void checkServerHasPackageResource(Vertx vertx, VertxTestContext testContext) {
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(vertx);
    webClient.get(8080, "localhost", "/router-package.txt")
      .as(BodyCodec.string())
      .send(testContext.succeeding(response -> testContext.verify(() -> {
        assertEquals(200, response.statusCode());
        testContext.completeNow();
      })));
  }
}
```

`checkServerHasStarted` passes, but the other two are failing with `404`. The two resource files exist here:

- `src/main/resources/router-root.txt`
- `src/main/resources/io/vertx/starter/router-package.txt`

And I have confirmed these files exist in the fat jar at their relative paths.

Ideally I would like to include these resources from another bundle (java project), but first things first.

Is there something I need to do with my routes to get either one of the failed tests to pass? I am just getting started with Vert.x, so I assume my setup is stupid somewhere.

Full Project: https://github.com/drkstr101/vertx-static-example

Cheers, and thanks in advance for any guidance!

**EDIT**

I realize there is a form of `StaticHandler.create` that accepts a `ClassLoader`, and is most likely how to go about this. However from what I read this should not be necessary, and also there is a deprecating warning about the feature being removed in the next version. May I assume that that serving resources from the classpath will be fully working once the feature is deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default folder for resources is `webroot`.

Create a `src/main/resources/webroot` folder in your project and move all the static content to it.
Or configure the `StaticHandler` to change the root folder.

Side note: for a catch-all route you can omit the path

```
router.route().handler(StaticHandler.create());
```

Comment: So, you're saying it's not possible to serve resources from classpath? That would pretty much eliminate vert.x as a viable solution for me. How unfortunate. :/

Comment: Ugg, sorry I misread your comment. Thanks for help!!